# What's the Window Message that the parent window receive when a new WindowControl is opened from it?

Tags: windows, winapi

When a user click in a button for example and open a new form, what's the Message that the parent window receive to detect that a new window was opened from it?

I saw that the parent window receive a messages like WM_PAINT. But this messages happens everytime a control has to be painted on the screen.

There's a unique message that the parent can identify a new opened window from it? If it's not, what can I do?

Thanks.

Comment: There is no such message. Have your button click handler send the parent a private message when it opens a form.

Comment: I don't have control of the application that handles the button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WM_PARENTNOTIFY Message (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632638(v=vs.85).aspx)

With WM_CREATE (0x0001) - LOWORD(wParam).

EDIT:

Like others said in comments, WM_PARENTNOTIFY will not work.

The another approach that I find is to Superclassing all WINDOW class after my MainWindow start to execute. In that way Windows OS will cal my own WndProc before the control initialize and then I can get the WM_NCREATE e WM_CREATE messages for the Window that will be created.

Thank you guys.

Comment: This is only Windows 8/Server 2012 and above, according to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh454920%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Comment: Strange... I'm using Win 7 and is happening!

Comment: Don't trust OS version numbers reported by MSDN documentation. They get skewed over time as support for old versions get dropped. `WM_PARENTNOTIFY` and `WM_EX_NOPARENTNOTIFY` have been around since Windows 95 and NT 3.1. See the "Supported OS Versions" comment in [this documentation](http://technet.microsoft.com/eS-es/library/hh454920.aspx)

Comment: In general, this will not work for child windows on a dialog. From the documentation: *"All child windows, except those that have the `WS_EX_NOPARENTNOTIFY` extended window style, send this message to their parent windows. **By default, child windows in a dialog box have the `WS_EX_NOPARENTNOTIFY` style**"*.